# not finding string in list

Tags: python, string, list, element

I'm looking for a string that exists in a list, to get the index of the string so I can insert the contents of list B into list A.

My code says the string is NOT in the list, and I don't know why (since it's there!).  Thx!

```
HEADER = ['ROAD_ID: R1.6', 'ROAD_TYPE: Curve', 'ARC_RADIUS: 1650.000000', 'SPIRAL_LEN1: 300.000000', 'SPIRAL_LEN2: 300.000000', 'SUPERELEVATION: 0.030000', 'CONTROL_POINT: 56551.970145 41423.581706 117.415152', 'VCURVE_LEN: 1298.247591', 'VCURVE_MIN: 20.000000', 'SLOPE1: 0.020632', 'SLOPE2: 0.019981', 'PATHNAME: Default Road', 'SPEED: 45.000000', 'NO_PASSING: FALSE', 'STORE_HPR: FALSE', 'NUM_POINTS: 130']
K_WIDTH = 'WIDTH: '
W_REC = ['PROFILE_POINT: 25.500 0.000','PROFILE_POINT: -25.500 0.00','WIDTH: 51.000','CENTER2LEFT: 25.500']
what = 'PATHNAME:'

for n in HEADER:
    print n, type(n)
    if what in n:
        print '////////////////////'
        print 'Found:', what, type(n)

if not K_WIDTH in HEADER:
    print 'Looking for:', what

    if what in HEADER:
        where = HEADER.index(what)
        HEADER.insert(where,w_rec)
    else:
        print 'Not found', what
```

Output:

```
ROAD_ID: R1.6 <type 'str'>
ROAD_TYPE: Curve <type 'str'>
ARC_RADIUS: 1650.000000 <type 'str'>
SPIRAL_LEN1: 300.000000 <type 'str'>
SPIRAL_LEN2: 300.000000 <type 'str'>
SUPERELEVATION: 0.030000 <type 'str'>
CONTROL_POINT: 56551.970145 41423.581706 117.415152 <type 'str'>
VCURVE_LEN: 1298.247591 <type 'str'>
VCURVE_MIN: 20.000000 <type 'str'>
SLOPE1: 0.020632 <type 'str'>
SLOPE2: 0.019981 <type 'str'>
PATHNAME: Default Road <type 'str'>
////////////////////
Found: PATHNAME: <type 'str'>
SPEED: 45.000000 <type 'str'>
NO_PASSING: FALSE <type 'str'>
STORE_HPR: FALSE <type 'str'>
NUM_POINTS: 130 <type 'str'>
Looking for: PATHNAME:
Not found PATHNAME:
```

Comment: But you really do not have `'WIDTH: '` in `HEADER` list

Comment: More to the point, there is no item `'PATHNAME:'` in `HEADER`, but it's in one of the items in `HEADER`. So you need to check each item to see if it contains your target string.

Comment: If you want to check if that particular item exists in HEADER, use `startswith`. EX: `n.startswith(what)` and if True then get the index as `HEADER.index(n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The substring `PATHNAME:` is part of the list of strings variable named `HEADER`. Therefore,  you have to iterate through every individual string and match it with your substring, like this `if what in s for s in HEADER`, the updated code is given below:

```
HEADER = ['ROAD_ID: R1.6', 'ROAD_TYPE: Curve', 'ARC_RADIUS: 1650.000000', 'SPIRAL_LEN1: 300.000000', 'SPIRAL_LEN2: 300.000000', 'SUPERELEVATION: 0.030000', 'CONTROL_POINT: 56551.970145 41423.581706 117.415152',
          'VCURVE_LEN: 1298.247591', 'VCURVE_MIN: 20.000000', 'SLOPE1: 0.020632', 'SLOPE2: 0.019981', 'PATHNAME: Default Road', 'SPEED: 45.000000', 'NO_PASSING: FALSE', 'STORE_HPR: FALSE', 'NUM_POINTS: 130']
K_WIDTH = 'WIDTH: '
W_REC = ['PROFILE_POINT: 25.500 0.000', 'PROFILE_POINT: -25.500 0.00',
         'WIDTH: 51.000', 'CENTER2LEFT: 25.500']
what = 'PATHNAME:'

for n in HEADER:
    print n, type(n)
    if what in n:
        print '////////////////////'
        print 'Found:', what, type(n)

if not K_WIDTH in HEADER:
    print 'Looking for:', what

    where = [HEADER.index(i) for i in HEADER if what in i]
    if (where):
        HEADER.insert(where[0], w_rec)
    else:
        print 'Not found', what
```

Comment: You won't get the index using **HEADER.index(what)**. Because there is no string like *"PATHNAME"* in the *HEADER* list

Comment: @H.Sodi Thanks for the heads up. I just updated my answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Still you are iterating the list twice (one for finding if substring exist and if found, other for finding index) which is unnecessary. Refer my answer. It can be done in one loop keeping track of index.

Comment: @H.Sodi Updated my answer yet again. I noticed the index lookup was fulfilling both purposes i.e. finding the index and checking if the substring existed. It returns an empty list if there's no matching string.

Comment: This code does what it should except the W_REC list is inserted whole instead of the values in W_REC - I think I can cope with that.  The initial loop is extraneous given responses pointing out that a substring needs to be checked against all list elements.  And that was part of my attempt to debug.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that when you define **what**, it is defined as 'PATHNAME: '. This str by itself is not in the list, it is only part of a string and the program doesn't recognize. To fix it, I would change **what** to be equal to 'PATHNAME: Default Road'. I tested this in a program and it seems to sense it is there. I hope this helps.

Comment: Won't it be better if we change the code and make it able to fetch the string containing the word we want to find ?

Comment: You either have to change the "what" variable or change the item in the list. Another alternative could be directly referencing the item in the list and sensing if the item contains the variable.

Comment: My point is : *PATHNAME:* is like a label and *Default Road* is the value. Value can change so it's better if the program can find the list item that contain the label PATHNAME rather than hardcoding the value along with it.

Comment: In that case I think a dictionary would be better for this program, if it was a dictionary they could find the "Default Road" value with "PATHNAME: " as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try iterating and finding if there is a match for your substring

**Code**

```
HEADER = ['ROAD_ID: R1.6', 'ROAD_TYPE: Curve', 'ARC_RADIUS: 1650.000000', 'SPIRAL_LEN1: 300.000000', 'SPIRAL_LEN2: 300.000000', 'SUPERELEVATION: 0.030000', 'CONTROL_POINT: 56551.970145 41423.581706 117.415152', 'VCURVE_LEN: 1298.247591', 'VCURVE_MIN: 20.000000', 'SLOPE1: 0.020632', 'SLOPE2: 0.019981', 'PATHNAME: Default Road', 'SPEED: 45.000000', 'NO_PASSING: FALSE', 'STORE_HPR: FALSE', 'NUM_POINTS: 130']
K_WIDTH = 'WIDTH: '
W_REC = ['PROFILE_POINT: 25.500 0.000','PROFILE_POINT: -25.500 0.00','WIDTH: 51.000','CENTER2LEFT: 25.500']
what = 'PATHNAME:'

for n in HEADER:
    print n, type(n)
    if what in n:
        print '////////////////////'
        print 'Found:', what, type(n)

if not K_WIDTH in HEADER:
    print 'Looking for:', what

    found = 0
    for i in range(0,len(HEADER)):
        if what in HEADER[i]:
            found = 1
            HEADER.insert(i,W_REC)
    if found == 0:
        print 'Not found', what
```

Comment: I like H. Sodi but 2 issues: w_rec should be W_REC, and the code as written is dumping multiple W_REC instead of 1.  I should say, as I modified it!

Comment: Resolved the W_REC issue. I am no so clear with what you want to achieve ultimately, but from your question code I infered that you need to insert the W_REC list in HEADER at the position where you find string containing "PATHNAME:".

Comment: Sorry. I want the content of W_REC inserted.Unmodified it's still dumping multiple W_RECs into HEADER.  Appreciate your thoughts though!

Comment: Adeels output is closest to desired output. 
I should have been clearer!                                             
ROAD_ID: R1.6
ROAD_TYPE: Curve
ARC_RADIUS: 1650.000000
SPIRAL_LEN1: 300.000000
SPIRAL_LEN2: 300.000000
SUPERELEVATION: 0.030000
CONTROL_POINT: 56551.970145 41423.581706 117.415152
VCURVE_LEN: 1298.247591
VCURVE_MIN: 20.000000
SLOPE1: 0.020632
SLOPE2: 0.019981
['PROFILE_POINT: 25.500 0.000', 'PROFILE_POINT: -25.500 0.00', 'WIDTH: 51.000', 'CENTER2LEFT: 25.500']
PATHNAME: Default Road
SPEED: 45.000000
NO_PASSING: FALSE
STORE_HPR: FALSE
NUM_POINTS: 130